# IIS 7.5: Replace web app with redirect to another

Tags: asp.net, iis

Hello - I'm using IIS 7.5 to host a web site with several web apps.  For the sake of discussion, let's say it is comprised of the following:

> http://hostname/app1
>
> http://hostname/app2

I have a bunch of users that use http://hostname/app1 as their bookmarked hyperlink but I want to delete that app and replace it with app2.  In my case, app2 has a more appropriate name so I can't just overwrite app1's content.

Is there a way to redirect users to app2 when they browse to app1 within IIS?  I tried the Http Redirect but it appears to work for the whole website and I just want to apply it to one application.  I see the Url Rewrite tool but it seems like overkill and I'm just trying to replace a visit to the app's main page, not rewrite urls...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory, empty your site's pages and replace their content with:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://hostname/app2" />`

If you are looking for a catch-all scenario, URL Rewrites would be ideal. For example http://hostname/app1/page1 http://hostname/app1/page2 may not get caught with below without replacement in both places.